# Compiling an Win8 app from a Win8 Metro app (and possibly run it sandboxed)

Tags: windows-8

I have a bit of a weird question. Is is possible to maybe **CodeDom** or **Emit** compile a Win8 Metro app (.NET or HTML5/JS) from within a Win8 Metro app and then run it (not install it, just run it until user closes it/stops it)? I guess it is sort of a MEF-ish need.

I haven't been able to find any references to this kind of need. I've tried to wade through what **Rosetta** is/does, but haven't gotten very far in understanding how it is better/different than CodeDom or Emit and if it could even be what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you find a way to do this, it will surely earn you a rejection letter from the app store

Comment: @RobertLevy: do you have any documentation to support your claim?

Comment: just common sense... they are putting all kinds of structure in place to verify that apps follow certain policies.  runtime code generation breaks their ability to do that.  therefore runtime code generation will itself not be allowed

Comment: Thanks, but I rather see something more official than "just common sense". Common sense would have been to change WinMo to a touch device and a larger screen in 2006, but that didn't happen...

Answer (score 3):

No.  Windows 8 Metro style apps can only access .NET Framework classes in the Core Profile (a subset of the full .NET Framework).  System.CodeDom is not part of the Core Profile.  If you have a Win8 CP machine installed, you can see the Core Profile reference assemblies with ILDasm or [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) at ...

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\
```

Check out [A .NET developer's view of Windows 8 app development](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-930C) from Build for a discussion of the .NET Profile for Metro style apps.

Comment: Very useful, thank you! I'll take an opportunity to read through the link.